# Using GUIDs as attributes to substitute in a stringtemplate.org template

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

Is there a way in template (stringtemplate.org 4 engine) to use a GUID as an attribute to be substituted or to reduce stringtemplate's expressiveness so it will not evaluate the value between the delimiters as anything other than an attribute lookup?

Example:
The following fails with a Antlr4.StringTemplate.Compiler.TemplateException.

```
Template template = new Template("{AAA04EC0-301F-11D3-BF1B-00C04F79AAAC}", '{', '}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Yes: The StringTemplate group syntax was updated to allow `-` characters to appear as part of an attribute name (but not as the first character). I'm not sure the template lexer was update to allow you to actually *use* such an attribute. You should file an issue on the issue tracker for the project:
https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/issues

No: An attribute name cannot start with a digit, so only GUID values starting with a letter would work.

Comment: Not quite what I'm seeing. "A-B" still throws, "A-" is accepted.   I'll file a defect regardless.